# How to compose a view with multiple parts having variables that are needed across?

Tags: php, view

I have 2 files in same folder

layout.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><?= isset($pageTitle) ? $pageTitle : '' ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    HERE COMES THE CONTENT
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

view.php

```
<?php $pageTitle = 'Welcome'; ?>

<h1>Content</h1>
```

What if I want to combine these two files and render the view properly??
What makes the problem for me is that the $pageTitle is inside view.php
and that view.php should be in place of 'HERE COMES THE CONTENT' of layout.php

How to solve this?

I tried with including the files one after another but it's not good because whichever file is included first it misses a variable from next included file.

Comment: Why do you need to set the page title in the body? And why do you need two separate files here?

Comment: It's not only about the page title. If I could make this happen it would bring so much flexibility. This is only a simple example of a bigger idea. I am building my own framework for learning purposes and want to replicate some very advanced stuff from other frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine PHP and HTML files into one (but of course, it needs still the `.php` extension to be properly processed) and create the content dynamically.

```
<?php
    // some PHP part
    $pageTitle = 'Welcome';
    $content = '<h1>Content</h1>';

    // OR, for dynamic load (separated files)
    ob_start();
    include_once('some/html/file.html'); /* or it could be another PHP file echoing content */
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><?php echo (isset($pageTitle)) ? $pageTitle : ''; /* some other PHP part */ ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <?php echo $content; /* print the content */ ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope, this is what you're asking for :)